# Choose VPC when creating a DMS replication instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-vpc, vpc, aws-dms

When using the command

```
aws dms create-replication-instance
```

How can I force/choose the VPC that will contain the instance ?

Comment: HelloV edited the question so it match his answer. But it does not match the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a DMS Replication Instance somewhere other than the default VPC and subnet, you need to first create a **replication subnet group**.  This is created with a name and a list of one or more subnet ids (all in the same VPC).

Reference for the aws-cli call to `create-replication-subnet-group`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dms/create-replication-subnet-group.html

You would then pass that resulting replication subnet group id to `create-replication-instance` command as the `--replication-subnet-group-identifier` option.

Reference for the the aws-cli call for `create-replication-instance`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dms/create-replication-instance.html

The DMS Replication Instance would then be created in the VPC determined by the subnet group.

Comment: This does not work for me :( I provide subnet group and then get an error indicating DMS instance created in another VPC.

Answer (score 1):

VPC is too broad. You need to specify the subnet in which you want the replication instance to be created. VPC can be derived from the subnet id.

[create-replication-instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dms/create-replication-instance.html)

> --replication-subnet-group-identifier (string)
>
> A subnet group to associate with the replication instance.

Comment: Yes I figured it out and forgot to delete the question. Please edit your answer to include a reference to the create-replication-subnet-group and I will accept it as the correct answer ( I think it will be more useful to others that way )